# How to extract string values from a URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to extract following values from the url mentioned below?

- layout2
- aqua

**code:**

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/dflyers/edit.html?layout2&aqua"
var dataLayout = // I need url string (layout2) here
var dataTheme = // I need url string (aqua) here
```

Can some one help to get mentioned values using jQuery/Javascript? Thanks

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: This looks like invalid url. Query string parameters must be of the form `key=value`

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - they don't actually.  That's perfectly valid.

Comment: See here ;-)
[Get query string values in JavaScript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Common Gateway Interface requires `key=value&...` but nothing in the HTTP protocol itself requires it.

Comment: @Archer, you are actually right. Thanks for this precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you just want to get those values from the mentioned url, and not any complex url parser, the most simple solution is:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/dflyers/edit.html?layout2&aqua";
var query = url.split('?')[1].split('&');
var dataLayout = query[0];
var dataTheme = query[1];

alert('layout '+dataLayout);
alert('theme '+dataTheme);​
```

Example [running in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VqJtf/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/dflyers/edit.html?layout2&aqua",
    qs = url.split('?')[1],
    dataLayout = qs.split('&')[0],
    dataTheme = qs.split('&')[1];
```

If you're getting the url from the location.href, you could use location.search instead to get just the querystring and skip a `split()`.

Comment: We think the same, keep it simple :D

Comment: Did'nt see your answer or I would'nt have posted, but I think it was just seconds apart ?

Comment: No worries, it happens sometimes

Comment: whatever happened to "don't repeat yourself"...?

Comment: @Alnitak - say what now?

Comment: @adeneo you're calling `qs.split()` twice

Comment: @Alnitak - that's just because it's faster - [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/array-vs-split10) ... ;-) ...

Comment: @adeneo your jsperf was incorrect - you're using `?` twice in the `array` test.  When fixed, the result is as expected - http://jsperf.com/array-vs-split10/2

Comment: @Alnitak - It was actually more of a joke, as it does'nt matter at all as four million iterations per second would only be noticeable if you used split a couple of million times to much!

Comment: @adeneo yeah, I know.  None-the-less, you just shouldn't call the same function twice to get each of its results, when one call would do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery then the BBQ plugin (by Ben Alman) has the functionality you are looking for:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/